# Generate Complex SQL with any ORM

Tags: linq, orm, code-generation

Following on from another question I have just asked...

As much as I love LINQ and other ORM's for speed of development, I am finding that it is actually quiet difficult/impossible/slower (in terms of development speed) to generate complex SQL.

By complex, I mean more advanced SQL such as CTE's, Merge statements, query hints etc...

Can this be done by any existing ORM product? (I have exclusively used MS-L2S)

I am finding more and more than I am resorting to writing the SPROC and calling it through LINQ... Seems to be the best of both worlds at the moment... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate allows you to write native SQL code.  I'm sure that this feature should only be used when you really want some complex stuff that the ORM isn't able to handle properly.

Doesn't EF have a similar feature ?

Comment: It does - ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx) is one way, although you can easily just execute a plain ol' DBCommand, as well.